# Return most recent result from the resultset of two tables

Tags: sql, union, aggregate-functions

I have a query that searches the most recent transactions from two tables. The query works fine and returns *2 results*.

```
    SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY lower(tb1.email) order by tb1.reserve_date DESC) AS ranking,
    tb1.id,
    tb1.reserve_date
  FROM TableTester1 tb1
  UNION
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY lower(tb2.email) order by tb2.reserve_date DESC) AS ranking,
    tb2.id,
    tb2.reserve_date
  FROM TableTester2 tb2
  )
WHERE ranking = 1;
```

But according to the requirement, I still have to trim this down and get the more recent one. So, the query should only return *1 result*.

I have read aggregate functions and tried using **MAX()** and **GROUP BY** functions as seen below:

```
SELECT MAX(reserve_date)
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY lower(tb1.email) order by tb1.reserve_date DESC) AS ranking,
    tb1.id,
    tb1.reserve_date
  FROM TableTester1 tb1
  UNION
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY lower(tb2.email) order by tb2.reserve_date DESC) AS ranking,
    tb2.id,
    tb2.reserve_date
  FROM TableTester2 tb2
  )
WHERE ranking = 1;
```

but it only results to a *ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression* error.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Your union of two queries using row number is unusual, and you should explain why you are doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the `row_number()` after the `union all`:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM (SELECT tt.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY reserve_date DESC) as seqnm
      FROM ((SELECT tb1.id, tb1.reserve_date
             FROM TableTester1 tb1
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT tb2.id, tb2.reserve_date
             FROM TableTester2 tb2
            )
           ) tt
     ) tt
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just limit to the first two:

```
SELECT id, reserve_date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LOWER(tb1.email)
            ORDER BY reserve_date DESC) AS rn,
        id,
        reserve_date
    FROM TableTester1
) t
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

If you instead really mean all records corresponding to the first two by *rank*, then you may replace `ROW_NUMBER` with either `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`, depending on which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY lower(tb.email) order by tb.reserve_date DESC) AS ranking,
tb1.id,
tb1.reserve_date from 
(select * FROM TableTester1 tb1

UNION

select *  FROM TableTester2 tb2
)tb)B
WHERE ranking = 1;
```